# Importing csv files containing multiple geometries in postgis

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgis

I have the following data in tab delimited csv file (containing latitude and longitude of places):

```
<place1>    <geo>   "POLYGON((-5.8335446 43.3655635,-5.8336337 43.3655207,-5.8349218 43.3673341,-5.8345197 43.3674013,-5.8336182 43.3660938,-5.8335037 43.365924,-5.8334505 43.3658461,-5.8334702 43.3657311,-5.8335446 43.3655635))" .
<place2>    <geo>   "POINT((-5.8374796 43.3687922))" .
<place3>    <geo>   "LINESTRING((-5.8427265 43.3678474,-5.8421236 43.3677908))" .
<place4>    <geo>   "MULTIPOINT((-5.8445678 43.3589236,-5.8435222 43.358205,-5.8429834 43.3575551,-5.8429127 43.3572642))" .
```

I want to import this data into postgis. In order to do so, I need to create a table in my database first. I know I can create a table for one specific geometry(e.g. for POINT) using:

```
create table myTable (firstColumn varchar(100));
SELECT AddGeometryColumn( 'myTable', 'geom', 4269, 'POINT', 2 );
```

But I am not able to understand as to how can I import my csv file containing varied geometries into postgres in one column of single table myTable. I also want to construct a single "gist" index on the top of myTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a generic "GEOMETRY" column, using

`SELECT AddGeometryColumn( 'myTable', 'geom', 4269, 'GEOMETRY', 2 );`

Then add the gist index as usual.